# Java ASCII и (char)

Tags: java, ascii

Вводил разные значения в

```
 System.out.println((char)855);
```

и сверял полученный результат с таблицей ASCII. Результаты сходились только до 127. Почему дальше результаты не сходились? (ведь таблицу расширили до 256) И почему можно вообще использовать такие значения как 855?

Comment: Размер `char` 2 байта (2^16). Почему нет? Первые 127 символов - стандартная таблица. Больше 127 - это расширенная таблица ASCII.

Comment: «ведь таблицу расширили до 256» — ничего подобного, в ASCII всегда было и есть ровно 128 символов

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что в `Java` строки представляются в стандарте `Unicode`. Поэтому множество представимых символов не ограничено таблицей `ASCII`. Можете [здесь](http://unicode-table.com/ru) посмотреть таблицу `Unicode`. Тип `char` в `Java` 2-х байтовый, т.е. в нём представимы числа от 0 до 65535, с помощью которых представляются символы в кодировке [UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Символом с кодом 855 является [Комбинируемый надстрочный правый полукруг](https://unicode-table.com/ru/0357/). Собственно, он и выводится у вас в программе.